# Mostrar array en html PHP

Tags: php, array, phpmyadmin, php7, html-tabla

tengo el siguiente problema, resulta que tengo el siguiente arreglo:

```
array(3) { 
   [0]=> array(9) {
        ["id"]=> string(2) "15"
        ["estilo"]=> string(4) "0053"
        ["codigo"]=> string(10) "4444444.23"
        ["color"]=> string(5) "verde"
        ["punto"]=> string(2) "23" 
        ["material"]=> string(7) "vacuno" 
        ["precio"]=> string(3) "130" 
        ["stock_vendido"]=> int(2)
        ["total"]=> string(3) "260" 
   }
   [1]=> array(9) {
        ["id"]=> string(2) "16" 
        ["estilo"]=> string(4) "0053" 
        ["codigo"]=> string(10) "4444444.25" 
        ["color"]=> string(5) "verde" 
        ["punto"]=> string(2) "25" 
        ["material"]=> string(7) "vacuno" 
        ["precio"]=> string(3) "130" 
        ["stock_vendido"]=> int(1) 
        ["total"]=> string(3) "130" 
   }
   [2]=> array(9) { 
        ["id"]=> string(2) "10" 
        ["estilo"]=> string(1) "0058" 
        ["codigo"]=> string(10) "1232323.23" 
        ["color"]=> string(2) "rojo" 
        ["punto"]=> string(2) "23" 
        ["material"]=> string(2) "sintetico" 
        ["precio"]=> string(3) "2.8" 
        ["stock_vendido"]=> int(3) 
        ["total"]=> string(3) "8.4" 
    }
}
```

al momento de mostrar este arreglo en una tabla HTML con ayuda de un foreach me genera la tabla pero me muestra 3 filas.
Aquí el detalle es que solamente debo mostrar 2 filas, ya que un estilo se repite, sin embargo debo de mostrar esas dos filas pero cuando el estilo sea igual debo también mostrar el punto de zapato que compro. Algo similar a esto, lo hice en excel la forma en como debería de quedar la tabla en html:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde descripción sea solamente el estilo, y si hay mas de un punto de un estilo igual que se vaya agregando en su respectiva celda de punto del zapato.

Espero puedan ayudarme amigos, se los agradecería mucho amigos.

Hasta ahora así muestro la información de ese arreglo, pero como menciono me muestra 3 filas.

```
echo '<table style="font-size:8px; padding:5px 10px;">

    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:8px; width:78.14px; text-align:justify">Descripción</td>
    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">22</td>
    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">22.5</td>
            <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">23</td>
            <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">23.5</td>
            <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">24</td>
            <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">24.5</td>
            <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">25</td>
    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">25.5</td>
    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">26</td>
    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">26.5</td>
            <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">27</td>
            <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">27.5</td>
            <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">28</td>
            <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">28.5</td>
            <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">29</td>
    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">29.5</td>
    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">30</td>
    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">30.5</td>
            <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">31</td>
            <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">31.5</td>
            <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">32</td>

            ';
        foreach ($array85 as $val){
                $name = $val["estilo"] . '-' . $val["material"] . '-' . $val["color"];
                $punto = $val["punto"];

                if ($punto == "22") {
                    $stock22 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "22.5") {
                    $stock225 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "23") {
                    $stock23 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "23.5") {
                    $stock235 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "24") {
                    $stock24 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "24.5") {
                    $stock245 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "25") {
                    $stock25 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "25.5") {
                    $stock255 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "26") {
                    $stock26 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "26.5") {
                    $stock265 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "27") {
                    $stock27 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "27.5") {
                    $stock275 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "28") {
                    $stock28 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "28.5") {
                    $stock285 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "29") {
                    $stock29 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "29.5") {
                    $stock295 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "30") {
                    $stock30 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "30.5") {
                    $stock305 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "31") {
                    $stock31 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "31.5") {
                    $stock315 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "32") {
                    $stock32 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                }
                echo '<tr>



                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:8px; width:78.14px; text-align:justify">'.$name.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock22.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock225.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock23.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock235.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock24.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock245.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock25.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock255.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock26.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock265.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock27.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock275.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock28.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock285.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock29.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock295.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock30.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock305.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock31.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock315.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock32.'</td>



    </tr>
   ';
        }
        echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Puedes poner el código donde muestras el arreglo, para saber que puede ser. Saludos!

Comment: listo @JoseCansecoJiorchovic ya edite la pregunta y agregue el código donde muestro la información.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo vas a tener que agrupar los datos en otro arreglo que acumule los valores que necesitas para mostrar. Te recomiendo que mires https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: Sugiero que debes de hacer la comparación con el nombre para no mostrar 3 renglones, si el nombre ya existe, editar las columnas, ahorita en un momento mas paso algo de código. Saludos @JoseRangel

Comment: @Jose Canseco Jiorchovic gracias amigo, ayer estaba intentando algo similar pero no me salió, lo importante aquí es mostrar estilos sin repetir pero poner las unidades compradas en sus respectivas columnas

Answer (score 2):

te comparto link donde viene ejemplo que te puede ayudar mucho.

[Ejemplo Muestra Array PHP en HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774304/display-an-array-in-html-table)

Dejo el codigo por si el enlace llega a tener incovenientes

```
<?php
$var['page'] = array('add', 'edit', 'delete', 'search');
$var['category'] = array('add', 'edit', 'export');

$pages = count($var['page']);
$categories = count($var['categories']);
$max = ($pages > $categories ? $pages : $categories);

echo '<table>';
for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td>{$var['page'][$i]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$var['category'][$i]}</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Cabe mencionar que esta pendiente lo que ya nos explico sobre lo que necesita

Saludos

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], pues los aportes que son solo enlaces se consideran de baja calidad

Comment: @Aprendiz Enterado...

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/165271)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, si me paso por la mente agregar el codigo en la respuesta, pero no me paso el hecho de que el link ya no se encontrara. En un momento mas hago algunos ajustes. Gracias @BenderPaisa

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la solución!

```
foreach($array85 as $el){
    $keys = ['stock_vendido', 'punto'];
    $size = array_filter($el, function($v, $k) use ($keys) { return in_array($k, $keys); }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

   if (!isset($report[$el['estilo']])) {
      $shoe = array_filter($el, function($v, $k) use ($keys) { return !in_array($k, $keys); }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
      unset($shoe['total']);
      $report[$el['estilo']] = $shoe;
      $report[$el['estilo']]['tallajes'] = [];
    } 
    $report[$el['estilo']]['tallajes'][$size['punto']] = $size['stock_vendido'];
}
```